# Persistent state in React Native: setting state from AsyncStorage doesn't update component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to get a persisted state on a component.

Using console logs I can see that AsyncStorage appears to save and load the value, and that the value appears to be stringified/parsed correctly.

The state appears to also be updated correctly, based off the value that's loaded from storage.

However, the `<SegmentedControlTab>` component never shows with the correct `selectedIndex`; it always defaults to 0 or whatever I manually assign to the state.  I expected that once the state is updated in the `componentDidMount` function that the `<SegmentedControlTab>` would automatically update the `selectedIndex` to reflect this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, ScrollView, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import SegmentedControlTab from 'react-native-segmented-control-tab';


class Home extends Component {

  state = {
    //units: 1    //0=metric, 1=Imperial, 2=cups
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {   //Load unit setting
      AsyncStorage.getItem('units').then((value) => {
        if (JSON.parse(value) === 0 || JSON.parse(value) === 1 || JSON.parse(value) === 2) {
          this.setState({ units: JSON.parse(value) });
        }
        console.log('Value loaded: ', JSON.parse(value));
        console.log('State: ', this.state.units);
      });
   }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <Text style={{ marginTop: 20, fontSize: 20 }}>Settings and that.</Text>
        <SegmentedControlTab
          values={['Metric', 'Imperial', 'Cups']}
          // tabStyle={{ borderColor: styleBackground }}
          // activeTabStyle={{ backgroundColor: styleBackground, borderColor: styleBackground }}
          selectedIndex={this.state.units}
          onTabPress={async (event) => {
            try {
              await AsyncStorage.setItem('units', JSON.stringify(event));
            } catch (error) {
              console.log('Some kind of terrible error');
            }
            this.setState({ units: event });
            console.log('Current state unit: ', this.state.units);
          }}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Any suggestions where I'm going wrong?

Comment: is 'units' the only item stored? when calling getItem('units')

Comment: Hi @RyanTurnbull - yes, 'units' is the only key I need to store.  I just need to persist the load state of the SegmentedControlTab.

Comment: Okay good, was concerned when i saw that the state uses the same key name :P

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a case of a 3rd party control not working as expected; React Native's `<SegmentedControlIOS>` control works as expected with (similar to) the above code.  Guess I need to have a play around with the `<SegmentedControlTab>` or find an alternative...